# TypeError: object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)

Tags: python, inheritance, singleton

I would like to implement class with name MyClass. 
This class should be a singleton and it has to inherit from BaseClass.

In the end I came up with following solution:

```
import random


class Singleton(object):
    _instances = {}

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]


class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.value = random.random()
        self.data = data

    def asfaa(self):
        pass


class MyClass(BaseClass, Singleton):
    def __init__(self, data=3):
        super().__init__(data)
        self.a = random.random()


inst = MyClass(3)
```

Evrythig is working properly if `def __init__(self, data=3)` of MyClass doesn`t have any arguments.
Otherwise I am getting error

```
line 9, in __new__
cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)
```

How to suppply any arguments to MyClass?

Comment: Why does Singleton have a dictionary of instances?  It should ideally only be a single instance, and it will be easier to work with that way.  Also, you shouldn't create new Singleton instances yourself since that defeats the whole purpose of Singleton; you should use a get_instance() method that gives you the instance or initializes it for you if it's unavailable.

Comment: Using separate Singleton class I can simply make other classes as a Singleton by inheriting. When I will create instance of the class second time it will always return a first instance. However my question was different.

Comment: Yeah, that works too I guess; it's just more traditional to do it via a getInstance() method since it's kinda hard/impossible to do something like what you're doing in other languages like Java/C#/etc..  Also, Python doesn't even need Singletons technically, since you can store all of it in a separate module.  All that aside, I think I found the error to your actual question though, so I'll post an answer in a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, your error is `TypeError: object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)`.  If you look at your code you are doing `super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)`.  `super(Singleton, cls)` refers to the `object` class since your `Singleton` class is inheriting `object`.  You just need to change this:

`cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)`

to this:

`cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls)`

because `object` doesn't take in any additional arguments.